# Awaiting .map execution with Image processing

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hi so I asked this before but couldn't get an answer so was hoping this time someone would be kind enough to help out. I basically have a dropzone where i drop mulitple images then when i click on Submit i have a handlesubmit function. That function loops throught all the images and converts them to baseURL format using the FileReader() API. The problem is that once its all mapped and pushed into array i want to access that array and do stuff with it but right now the code isn't awaiting the .map execution and jumping straight to a console.log afterwards thats logging the array which is empty obviously. below is what i tried to do using promises but still couldn't get it to work:

```
    const functionWithPromise = async file => {
        let image = '';
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file.file);
        reader.onload = await function (){
            image = reader.result;
            console.log(image);
           setArr([...arr,image]);

        };//a function that returns a promise
        reader.onloadend = function(){
            Promise.resolve('ok');
        }
    };

    const anAsyncFunction = async file => {
        return functionWithPromise(file)
    };

    const getData = async (files) => {
        return Promise.all(files.map(file => anAsyncFunction(file)))
    };

    //Clicking submit after all files are dropped triggers this.
    const handleSubmit =  (files, allFiles) => {
        getData(files).then(r => console.log(arr))
            .catch(err=>console.log(arr))

        //I want to do some stuff here with the arr AFTER the mapping and pushing base64 values is complete.
    };
```

Comment: have you noticed any errors in your console? `reader.onload = await function (){ ..... }` makes absolutely NO SENSE ... you can't `await` a function declaration - well, you can, but the await is superfluous ... you're just creating a function there - you need to read up on how async/await works - not ONE of your functions needs to be `async`

Comment: actually, the `handleSubmit` could be async (the one function that isn't) to make the code more readable if asynchrony intimidates you - see https://pastebin.com/Crjaq6nz (by the way that pastebin code completely removes the redundant `anAsyncFunction` function)

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you for taking time out to respond yes i m not very good with async/await i will trying out the pastebin code now

Comment: @JaromandaX You're a saint man! Thank you so much! Could you answer below so i can accept and upvote it ?

Comment: @JaromandaX   although setArr([...arr,image]): isnt working right away and on button click i see only one value in there but it works directly if i create a simple array with let array = []. and then do array.push(image). Any hints on how to deal with that?

Comment: no idea what `setArr` is since you don't show it ... is it an asynchronous function?

Comment: @JaromandaX my bad. Its state basically. 
const [arr,setArr] = React.useState([]);

Comment: so, it's not asyncrhonous

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah so how can i set the state properly you know like manually pushing the array works but that doesn't seem very clean.